# F# query inner collections

Tags: lambda, f#

In F#, I cannot find an intuitive way of querying a collection based on the property of an item in an inner collection. For instance, consider the scenario of an address book. It contains multiple records of persons, each person can have multiple email addresses or phone numbers. The types are:

```cs
type Email = {Email : string}
type PhoneNumber = {Number : string}
type Person = {Name : string; EmailAdresses : seq<Email>; PhoneNumbers : seq<PhoneNumber>}
```

I want to write a function that tries to find a person based on a phone number. Since phone numbers are unique, I expect the function to return either either a single Person or no Person, e.g. the function signature becomes

```cs
string->seq<Person>->Person option
```

I've come up with

```cs
let ``find person by phone number`` number ppl= 
        ppl |> Seq.tryFind(fun r -> Seq.exists (fun p -> p.Number = number) r.PhoneNumbers)
```

Q1: In my opinion this query is not very readable, can it be written in any cleaner?

Q2: I'd also like to be able to query the other inner collection, e.g. the email addresses. Instead of defining yet another function `find person by email address`, I'd like to explore more generic approach. The following works:

```cs
let findPerson (propSelector : Person -> seq<'a>)  (pred : seq<'a> -> bool) ppl = 
     ppl |> Seq.tryFind (propSelector >> pred)
```

(Including the types for the sake of clarity.) To call this function I have to do

```cs
ppl |> findPerson (fun x -> x.EmailAdresses) (fun p -> p |> Seq.exists (fun n -> n.Email = "john.doe@nowhere.com"))
```

Once more the lambdas become ugly, especially the second one. Any suggestions on how to improve this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type Email = string
type PhoneNumber = string
type Name = string
type Person = 
    {Name:Name; EmailAddresses:seq<Email>; PhoneNumbers:seq<PhoneNumber>}

let findPerson (propSelector : Person -> seq<'a>)  (pred : 'a -> bool) = 
     Seq.tryFind (propSelector >> Seq.exists pred)   

let ``find person with john doe email``:(seq<Person> -> Person option) = 
    findPerson 
        (fun person -> person.EmailAddresses)
        (fun email -> email = "john.doe@nowhere.com")

// .. start with a sequence of people 
ppl |> ``find person with john doe email``

(* Alternate *)
ppl |> findPerson 
        (fun person -> person.EmailAddresses)
        (fun email -> email = "john.doe@nowhere.com")
```

Notes: types can be as simple as:

```
type Email = string
```

In findPerson, you do not need to mention ppl since without it you are returning a function which takes seq. Compare

```
let findPerson (propSelector : Person -> seq<'a>)  (pred : 'a -> bool) = 
     Seq.tryFind (propSelector >> Seq.exists pred)
```

to

```
let findPerson (propSelector : Person -> seq<'a>)  (pred : 'a -> bool) ppl = 
     ppl |>Seq.tryFind (propSelector >> Seq.exists pred)
```

I've moved the `Seq.exists` call into the findPerson method so that it does is not required in the lambda passed in. This allows the passed in function to focus on the item and not the whole sequence. Presumably, this method requires a property that is a sequence.

The final call can either be a call to

```
let ``find person with john doe email``:(seq<Person> -> Person option) = 
    findPerson 
        (fun person -> person.EmailAddresses)
        (fun email -> email = "john.doe@nowhere.com")
```

or simply

```
ppl |> findPerson 
        (fun person -> person.EmailAddresses)
        (fun email -> email = "john.doe@nowhere.com")
```

[Edit]

Furthermore, instead of parenthesis, you could consider piping the functions together. I think this reads a little more naturally.

```
let findPerson (propSelector : Person -> seq<'a>)  (pred : 'a -> bool) = 
     propSelector >> Seq.exists pred |> Seq.tryFind
```

yielding this

```
type Email = string
type PhoneNumber = string
type Name = string
type Person = 
    {Name:Name; EmailAddresses:seq<Email>; PhoneNumbers:seq<PhoneNumber>}

let findPerson (propSelector : Person -> seq<'a>)  (pred : 'a -> bool) = 
     propSelector >> Seq.exists pred |> Seq.tryFind

ppl |> findPerson 
        (fun person -> person.EmailAddresses)
        (fun email -> email = "john.doe@nowhere.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you really don't need one of the lambdas - the one starting with `fun p -> p |> Seq.exists`. Look closely: all that lambda does is simply pass its argument to another function. So why not use that another function instead of lambda itself?

```
ppl |> findPerson (fun x -> x.EmailAdresses) (Seq.exists (fun n -> n.Email = "john.doe@nowhere.com")))
```

To do away with lambdas completely, I would simply create dedicated accessor functions in the `Person` module (if you have it) or on the `Person` type:

```
type Email = { Email: string } 
   with static member get e = e.Email

type Person = {
   Name : string; 
   EmailAdresses : seq<Email>; 
   PhoneNumbers : seq<PhoneNumber> } 
   with static member emailAddresses p = p.EmailAddresses

// then:
ppl |> findPerson Person.emailAddresses (Seq.exists (Email.get >> ((=) "john.doe@nowhere.com")))
```

And finally, having a record with one field is really kind of overkill. If you want to make sure that `Email` is incompatible with `string` (which is generally a good idea), the idiomatic way to do that is with a single-case union type:

```
type Email = Email of string
```

Then you can do pattern matching that looks very nice and self-descriptive:

```
let validateEmail (Email e) = e.Contains '@'
```